# Java BufferedReader always throws a NumberFormatException for first Iteration

Tags: java

Why do I get the Not a number exception first and then get the correct output ?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class readfile {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr =new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader buff = null;
        FileInputStream fs = null;
        try {
            fs = new FileInputStream("/home/krishna/Documents/file/file");
            buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));

        String line = buff.readLine();
            while(line != null) {
                try {
                    arr.add(Integer.parseInt(line.trim()));
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                    //System.out.println("Not a number");
                 e.printStackTrace();
                }
                line = buff.readLine();
            }
        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.print(e);
         }
         sumOfArray(arr);
       }
     static void sumOfArray(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
        int sum=0;
        for(Integer a:arr) {
            System.out.print(a+"\t");
            sum = sum+a;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum is : "+" "+sum);
        }
   }
```

The File contains numbers from 1 to 9 with each number in new line and there is no space or empty line in the beginning.

Stacktrace prints the following exception

```
output:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at com.mojang.readfile.main(readfile.java:18)
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   Sum is :  45
```

Comment: ok. I understand why you don't understand. change this: catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Not a number");
                } into: catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

Comment: *"The File contains numbers from 1 to 9 with each number in new line and there is no space or empty line in the beginning."* - `Integer.parseInt(line.trim())` seems to beg to differ. Perhaps you should print each line and see what you're actually reading

Comment: so indeed the first line you read is invalid.

Comment: There is an empty line somewhere in your file. Could be at the start but also at the end or even in the middle. Most likely at the end if it is not at the start.

Comment: but there is no space or empty string at the beginning.

Comment: Why you are saying no space or empty string at the beginning , maybe at the end of line this occurred? Because you are printing number after adding all numbers to list. So see my answer and check your file.

Answer (score 1):

*In your file* , last line has a new line with `\n` i think . Be aware of end of file there is no new line. Check with counter or open file and delete last new line. That means file must be like this;

```
// -->remove all if some char is here!!
1\n
2\n
3\n
4\n
.
.
.
9   //--> there is no new line !!!!!
```

Or change your code ;

```
if(line != null && !line.isEmpty()){
     arr.add(Integer.parseInt(line.trim()));
}
```

Comment: ... how would that explain the formatting of the first line?

Comment: will be the same for first line , questioner should be the more careful for checking line.

Comment: according to the OP, this is not the case, so what is your point in posting this as an answer?

Comment: I think this is the case which i wrote , because he did not parse one line , because there is some extra new line. I tried to explain this problem.

Comment: And you can see the updated answer. In stacktrace `output:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`  there is empty string.

Comment: The if statement did the MAGIC, Thank you.

Comment: glad to help you. If it helped, approve or not.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a blank line in your input. I suggest using`Scanner` instead as it skips the whitespace for you.

```
public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String file = "/home/krishna/Documents/file/file";
        List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(file))) {
            while (in.hasNextInt())
                ints.add(in.nextInt());
        }
        sumOfArray(ints);
    }

    static void sumOfArray(List<Integer> ints) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (int a : ints) {
            System.out.print(a + "\t");
            sum += a;
        }
        System.out.println("\nSum is: " + sum);
    }
}
```